# How to create soap request and parse xml response in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, soap, response

The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response

```
POST /WayBillService/WayBillService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: services.rs.ge
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/get_buyer_waybills"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <get_buyer_waybills xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <su>string</su>
      <sp>string</sp>
      <itypes>string</itypes>
      <seller_tin>string</seller_tin>
      <statuses>string</statuses>
      <car_number>string</car_number>
      <begin_date_s>dateTime</begin_date_s>
      <begin_date_e>dateTime</begin_date_e>
      <create_date_s>dateTime</create_date_s>
      <create_date_e>dateTime</create_date_e>
      <driver_tin>string</driver_tin>
      <delivery_date_s>dateTime</delivery_date_s>
      <delivery_date_e>dateTime</delivery_date_e>
      <full_amount>decimal</full_amount>
      <waybill_number>string</waybill_number>
      <close_date_s>dateTime</close_date_s>
      <close_date_e>dateTime</close_date_e>
      <s_user_ids>string</s_user_ids>
      <comment>string</comment>
    </get_buyer_waybills>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <get_buyer_waybillsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <get_buyer_waybillsResult>xml</get_buyer_waybillsResult>
    </get_buyer_waybillsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried to create request:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url='https://services.rs.ge/WayBillService/WayBillService.asmx'

headers={"Content-Type": "text/xml"}
body = """
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <get_buyer_waybills xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <su>"UserName"</su>
      <sp>"Password"</sp>
      <itypes></itypes>
      <seller_tin></seller_tin>
      <statuses></statuses>
      <car_number></car_number>
      <begin_date_s>2021-01-01</begin_date_s>
      <begin_date_e>2021-02-05</begin_date_e>
      <create_date_s></create_date_s>
      <create_date_e></create_date_e>
      <driver_tin></driver_tin>
      <delivery_date_s></delivery_date_s>
      <delivery_date_e></delivery_date_e>
      <full_amount></full_amount>
      <waybill_number></waybill_number>
      <close_date_s></close_date_s>
      <close_date_e></close_date_e>
      <s_user_ids></s_user_ids>
      <comment></comment>
    </get_buyer_waybills>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
             """

response = requests.post(url=url, data = body, headers = headers)
print(response)
```

and get this answer: <Response [500]> - and then I tried to get data from this but failed. if you can give me some tips how to do this, because it's my first time, I would really appreciate. here is what I have tried:

```
r = response.content
tree = ET.fromstring(r)
ET.dump(tree)
```

and get this error: <ns0:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">ns0:Bodyns0:Faultns0:Codens0:Valuesoap:Receiver</ns0:Value></ns0:Code>ns0:Reason<ns0:Text xml:lang="en">Server was unable to process request. ---> Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 2, position 7.</ns0:Text></ns0:Reason><ns0:Detail /></ns0:Fault></ns0:Body></ns0:Envelope>

```
from zeep import Client
client=Client('https://services.rs.ge/WayBillService/WayBillService.asmx?WSDL')
response=client.service.get_buyer_waybills(su="Username", sp="Password", waybill_number="0621508410")
print(response)
```

Comment: Look at zeep https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/

Comment: I tried your payload in Postman and get HTTP 500. The response message suggests that at least some of the empty elements are not acceptable

Comment: thanks for your replay "balderman", "docs.python-zeep.org/en/master" - I will check this link and thanks for your help "BRutusFocus", that's maybe username and password is necessary, I typed "username" and "password" but without actual username and password it will be impossible to get any response.

Comment: There is whitespace immediately before the XML declaration (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`)  in your code. Try removing it. The error message is about that.

Comment: I tried with "zeep" and get this response:
Element WAYBILL_LIST at 0x1fbbc2052c0 - is this what I should get? I couldn't get any data from it.